# More JS AI causes slower AI movement in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, collision, bounding-box

I have a simple little game with one character as the player and four enemy characters. I created a very basic AI, that moves towards the player when the player is nearby. That all worked fine, but when I added AI-AI collision (using a bounding box model), it slowed it down tremendously, and exponentially the more AI there are. With four AI, they move quite slowly. 3 AI is a bit better. 2 is just perfect, and 1 is too fast.

I have the following function to calculate the AI movement when near a player.

```
function updateAI() {
    for (i = 0; i < aiCount; i++) {
        if (aiCounterAI >= aiCount) {
            aiCounterAI = 0;
        }
        checkArmyAIcol = armyAI[aiCounterAI][1];
        checkArmyAIrow = armyAI[aiCounterAI][2];
        enemySpeed = enemies[armyAI[aiCounterAI][0][0]][3];
        enemyPlayerCollision = false;
        if (playerBattle.xCoord - 6 <= checkArmyAIcol && playerBattle.xCoord + 6 >= checkArmyAIcol) {
            if (playerBattle.yCoord - 6 <= checkArmyAIrow && playerBattle.yCoord + 6 >= checkArmyAIrow) {
                if (playerBattle.x < armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] - 48) {
                    armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] = armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] - enemySpeed;
                    aiDirection = 'left';
                }
                if (playerBattle.x > armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] + 48) {
                    armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] = armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] + enemySpeed;
                    aiDirection = 'right';
                }
                if (playerBattle.y < armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] - 48) {
                    armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] = armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] - enemySpeed;
                    aiDirection = 'up'; 
                }
                if (playerBattle.y > armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] + 48) {
                    armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] = armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] + enemySpeed;
                    aiDirection = 'down'; 
                }
                checkBattleCollision('ai',aiCounterAI);
                armyAI[aiCounterAI][1] = Math.ceil(armyAI[aiCounterAI][3] / 48);
                armyAI[aiCounterAI][2] = Math.ceil(armyAI[aiCounterAI][4] / 48);
            }
        }
        aiCounterAI++;
    }
}
```

And finally I have this function to calculate the AI collision.

```
if (type == 'ai') {
    enemyEnemyCollision = false;
    if (aiCount > 1) {
    checkArmyAIcol1 = armyAI[ai][1];
    checkArmyAIrow1 = armyAI[ai][2];
    checkArmyAIx1 = armyAI[ai][3];
    checkArmyAIy1 = armyAI[ai][4];
    var aiCounter2 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < aiCount; i++) {
        if (aiCounter2 != ai) {
            checkArmyAIcol2 = armyAI[aiCounter2][1];
            checkArmyAIrow2 = armyAI[aiCounter2][2];
            checkArmyAIx2 = armyAI[aiCounter2][3];
            checkArmyAIy2 = armyAI[aiCounter2][4];
            // Check if the AI is near the other AI before checking if collision is true
            if (checkArmyAIcol1 - 1 <= checkArmyAIcol2 && checkArmyAIcol1 + 1 >= checkArmyAIcol2) {
                if (checkArmyAIrow1 - 1 <= checkArmyAIrow2 && checkArmyAIrow1 + 1 >= checkArmyAIrow2) {
                    if (checkArmyAIx1 < checkArmyAIx2 + 48 &&
                        checkArmyAIx1 + 48 > checkArmyAIx2 &&
                        checkArmyAIy1 < checkArmyAIy2 + 48 &&
                        checkArmyAIy1 + 48 > checkArmyAIy2) {
                        enemyEnemyCollision = true;
                        checkEnemyEnemyCollision(ai,aiCounter2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        aiCounter2++;
    }
}
}

function checkEnemyEnemyCollision(enemy1,enemy2) {
enemySpeed = enemies[armyAI[enemy1][0][0]][3];
    if (enemyEnemyCollision == true) {
        if (aiDirection == 'left') {
            armyAI[enemy1][3] = armyAI[enemy1][3] + enemySpeed;}
        if (aiDirection == 'right') {
            armyAI[enemy1][3] = armyAI[enemy1][3] - enemySpeed;}
        if (aiDirection == 'up') {
            armyAI[enemy1][4] = armyAI[enemy1][4] + enemySpeed;}
        if (aiDirection == 'down') {
            armyAI[enemy1][4]= armyAI[enemy1][4] - enemySpeed;}
        console.log("ya'll collided ya clumsy potatoes");
    }
}
```

The updateAI function is fast and runs great. Adding the collision (using a bounding box model) as said before slows it down a lot. These functions are called sixty times a second, through requestAnimationFrame in my gameloop. My guess is that it can't keep up fast enough in the collision with the frame rate so they just can't move much as they could otherwise. Yet, I don't know how to fix this. Does anyone have any suggestions? Bounding box collision and multiple moving items is new territory for me so I wouldn't mind suggestions on improving my code.

Comment: If it's working but you just want to improve it, this should probably be at Code Review.

Comment: It's working fine, albeit it works very slowly as I said, and I can't figure out how to get rid of the slowness. Can I not ask that question here or is Code Review better for this?

Comment: Usually, things that work should go to Code Review. But if you consider it so slow that it doesn't really work properly, i.e. is unusable, it's fine to keep the question here. Anyway, I'm sure you get the point, SO is for code that doesn't work, and CR is for code that works but you want another set of eyes to take a look.

Comment: What is the value of `aiCount` when it becomes too slow. You say 4 to me that make no sense, your code should easily test `4 * 3 = 12` AI to AI checks with time to spare (though plenty of room for improvement). The source of the problem does not lay in the code you have shown. The code may be interfering with other functions/code as you have a lot of undeclared (and thus global) variables.

Comment: aiCount is the total number of enemy AI, defined by the array.length in which they are stored. This number only changes when an enemy is killed and removed from the game. The code right now checks collision for each AI after each one individually moves.